# Is there a way to print a string into a new df column based off of the other values of two other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

My desired output would be the highlighted column

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that.

Comment: @Raj see my answer below ;)

Comment: Hi Richard one more thing. I have some letters that go beyond Z. Example: AC to AE would be "AC AD AE". Do you think you could make this happen?

Comment: @richardec ^ See above

Comment: @Raj that's a bit more tricky. Will you please ask a new question about this, since I've already answered this particular question? You can link it here.

Comment: Just posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454485/hello-is-there-a-way-to-print-a-string-into-a-new-df-column-based-off-of-the-oth

Comment: @richardec Thanks again for all this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ord` to convert the letters to numbers, `range` to generate a range of all the numbers in between, and `chr` to convert the numbers back to letters. Then use `df.apply()` with a lambda function and `axis=1` to do this for every row:

```
df['Final'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(chr(c) for c in range(ord(x['Letter start']), ord(x['Letter finish']) + 1)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Letter start Letter finish    Final
0            A             D  A B C D
1            C             E    C D E
2            K             M    K L M
```