# Expand range of excel-column-like values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an addition to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70453163/17242583).

Can this be built modified further to include letters that go beyond `Z`, like Excel columns do?

For example: `AC` to `AE` would be `AC AD AE`.

Comment: Would using an external module be OK?

Comment: Yes, I don't really know what that means but if you think I will be able to run it then sure!

Comment: done now. check the answer ;)

Comment: You don't need any external modules, it turns out.

Comment: @richardec Thank you so much for this. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Comment: Additions to posts should be edited into the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some functions which I translated from JavaScript (from [here](https://github.com/avilaton/excel-column-name)):

```
df['Finish'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(intToExcelCol(c) for c in range(excelColToInt(x['Letter start']), excelColToInt(x['Letter finish']) + 1)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Letter start Letter finish       Finish
0           AA            AD  AA AB AC AD
1           AC            AE     AC AD AE
2           AK            AM     AK AL AM
```

The functions you'll need are below:

```
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
clen = len(chars)

def intToExcelCol(number):
    colName = ''
    dividend = np.floor(abs(number))
    rest = 0

    while True:
        if dividend <= 0:
            break
        rest = int((dividend - 1) % clen)
        colName = chars[rest] + colName
        dividend = int((dividend - rest) / clen)

    return colName


def excelColToInt(colName):
    digits = colName.upper()
    number = 0

    for i in range(len(digits)):
        number += (chars.index(digits[i]) + 1) * pow(clen, len(digits) - i - 1)

    return number
```